# gem install with file system as source installs wrong gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have just started working with Ruby. I am trying to install a gem with local file system as source.

```
$gem source
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
file:///home/fox/shared/
```

when i try to install 'bundler' gem it actually installs 'bundler-unload' gem as below.

```
$gem install bundler --bindir /usr/bin --no-ri --no-rdoc
Successfully installed bundler-unload-1.0.2
1 gem installed
```

the directory contains both the gems by the way.

```
bundler-unload-1.0.2.gem
bundler-1.10.6.gem
```

Is there anything that I am missing here. Why would it install the wrong gem?

Comment: when installing gem specify version of the gem as well and see what you get.

Comment: @Zahid the behaviour is the same even when version is specified

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the gem installer code and found the following.
First, the gem installer looks at the current directory to find the gems. It looks for *. It finds two gems (since i was running from the gems source directory) but sorts and reverse orders it and chooses the first one which is not the right gem. It does not do version check also when looking at the local directory. To workaround this i gave 'gem install bundler-1.10.6' which is working. By the way if i run 'gem install' from some other directory it is not able to find any gems from the 'file:' source.